# Requiring static images in React-Native

Tags: react-native, screen-density, pixel-ratio

My RN app (v0.19.0, ios and android) requires a loading/splash screen (there can be occasionally some data to load at startup), so I am trying to understand how to provide the right set of images for this screen across various devices.

Code is:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image style={styles.image} source={require('../assets/splash/Default.png')} resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.cover} />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

As far as I can tell, I need to provide a set of images with the right pixel ratio? How is that even relevant to the various screen sizes? Furthermore, [RN docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#content) only mention 2x and 3x, but docs on [PixelRatio](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pixelratio.html#content) indicate there's also a 1.5 and 3.5? (And, how is that indicated in the file name? Is it check@3.5x.png?) How do I account for portrait vs landscape orientation?

The docs seem surprisingly light on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

react-native doesn't (IIRC) have any support for choosing image size based on orientation and size automatically.

I would suggest instead that you build a 'SplashScreen' component and lay it out using flexbox as usual. 
That'll have the added benefit of saving you from having to provide dozens of images at different sizes!